# Nested vs. Chained Unions

Tags: performance, linq, ienumerable

Logically speaking, the following are all identical:

```
var foo = (  A.Union(B).Union(C).Union(D)  ).ToList();
var bar = (  A.Union(B.Union(C.Union(D)))  ).ToList();
var baz = (  D.Union(C.Union(B.Union(A)))  ).ToList();
```

They should all return exactly the same Lists at the end.

---

**What (if anything) are the differences between them?**

I would guess that the only difference is a performance related issue of how often you iterate through each of the collections? And that `foo` and `baz` then have exactly the same performance - iterating over `A` 4 times, but over `D` only once?

Is that right?

**Are the any other interesting properties that might lead you to caring about doing one rather than the other?**

Comment: None of these will iterate anything more than once. All inputs will be iterated in order, left-to-right. The only difference in result will be the order of the output, and (if it matters) the *exact* items returned where any are "equal".

Comment: @Rawling How do you propose to list the elements of A & B without ever looking at any element of either collection more than once?

Comment: [`Union` source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8c5b1699640b46dc). Although I did just write a console app to check.

Comment: @Rawling cool ... what do you think `set.Add()` does? ;)

Comment: @Rawling or `.ToList()` for that matter.

Comment: It adds it to a hashset. It's an O(1) operation and doesn't require, as per your initial question, any of the collections to be iterated more than once. And the `ToList` at the end of each line isn't really relevant.

Comment: Ah ... so ... I mis-spoke when I said iterate ... I agree that it isn't invoking the Enumerable generator repeatedly.... I did however assume that HashSets were not `O(1)` and thus meant "how many comparison operations occur" ... I feel a bit confused about how HashSets can be `O(1)`, but that's my problem not yours :)

Comment: Hang on .... No ... I was right! Union is iterating through both sides of it's set ... so if `A` is much larger than `B` then your performance will be different!

Comment: Cost of foo is `3a + 3b + 2c +d` where `a .. d` are the sizes of `A..D` respectively.

Comment: I think you are along the right lines, @Brondahl, but the lazy iterable behaviour of linq complicates things here. The items are not "iterated" more than once, but they are examined by linq's "yield return" state machines a varying number of times. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While dasblinkenlight is right that the items are each iterated exactly once, the three versions may still have measurable performance differences, depending on your objects.

The items will be inserted into a different number of Hashsets, depending on how far down the Union tree they are.

While inserting into a Hashset is nominally `O(1)`, it does have a cost, and it is not always constant in practice, depending on the details of your objects.

When an item is inserted into a Hashset, `GetHashCode` is called, and the item needs to be compared using `Equals` to any other objects in the set that have the same int hashcode. For extremely complex objects, `GetHashCode` may be expensive. If the items hashkeys are not widely distributed, then `Equals` may be called, which may be expensive.

The following demo, based on @dasblinkenlight's answer shows `GetHashCode` being called a different number of times depending on the `Union` ordering. I have not demoed `Equals` being called in the case of hash collisions, but you can try that out if you desire.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test {
    public static void Main() {
            var A = new VisibleIterator("A");
            var B = new VisibleIterator("B");
            var C = new VisibleIterator("C");
            var D = new VisibleIterator("D");
            Console.WriteLine("--- A.Union(B).Union(C).Union(D)");
            var foo = (A.Union(B).Union(C).Union(D)).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("--- A.Union(B.Union(C.Union(D)))");
            var bar = (A.Union(B.Union(C.Union(D)))).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("--- D.Union(C.Union(B.Union(A)))");
            var baz = (D.Union(C.Union(B.Union(A)))).ToList();
    }
}

    class VisibleIterator : IEnumerable<VisibleHasher> {
        private readonly string name;
        public VisibleIterator(string name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public IEnumerator<VisibleHasher> GetEnumerator() {
            for (var i = 0 ; i != 4 ; i++) {
                var res = name+i;
                Console.WriteLine("Iterating " + res);
                yield return new VisibleHasher(res);
            }
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    class VisibleHasher {
        private readonly string val;

        public VisibleHasher(String val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() {
            Console.WriteLine("Hashing '" + val + "'");
            return val.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/NlUyrJ) (based on dasblinkenlight's answer)

### Alternative Approach

If you think the costs of these hash insertions may be significant, then the following should guarantee one hash insertion per item:

```
A.Concat(B).Concat(C).Concat(D).Distinct().ToList()
```

Answer (score 5):

None of these solutions iterates its arguments multiple times. Moreover, arguments are iterated in the order they are given in the text, which is `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` for `foo` and `bar`, and `D`, `C`, `B`, `A` for `baz`.

You can demonstrate this with a simple generator that prints the items it returns as you iterate:

```
class VisibleIterator : IEnumerable<string> {
    private readonly string name;
    public VisibleIterator(string name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() {
        for (var i = 0 ; i != 4 ; i++) {
            var res = name+i;
            Console.WriteLine(res);
            yield return res;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/gMyo2D)

The reason why the collections are not enumerated multiple times is that `UnionIterator<T>`, the code behind `Union<T>`, keeps a hash set of items that have been visited:

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> UnionIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer) {
    Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource element in first)
        if (set.Add(element)) yield return element;
    foreach (TSource element in second)
        if (set.Add(element)) yield return element;
}
```

There may be a small difference in performance caused by the size of `Set<TSource> set` inside `UnionIterator<T>`. There would be three such sets in each of your example - one per `Union` call. Top-level `set` always ends up with all members of the `Union` result. Intermediate `set`s, though, may have more items or fewer items, depending on the order in which you combine your collections, and on the relative number of items in each collection.

Comment: I just did `var a = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.Select(i => { Console.WriteLine("A: " + i); return i; })` for the iterators :)

Comment: Yeah, your last paragraph is the thing I was trying to ask about! Apologies for the poorly expressed Question :(